# Comment wizardry

Tags: language-agnostic, comments

I am not a level 60 wizard yet, so I've got a question based on the following sentence in the Wikipedia article on [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_%28programming%29#Non-orthogonality):

> Any comment that has an effect on the code is magic.

How is that? In what languages is such a thing possible? More specifically, what effect can a comment have on the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magic comments take various forms. In Ruby, a comment can be placed at the top of the file, which specifies an encoding that the interpreter will use when reading in the file:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

[more](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings)

---

In Unix systems, the first line can be a shebang. In any language with octothorpes for comments, this ammounts to a comment that the OS reads to decide how to interpret the file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello from bash
```

[more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

---

In Haskell, certain types of comments known as pragmas can be used to switch on (or off) language features.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, NoTypeFamilies #-}
```

[more](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/pragmas.html)

Comment: I'm not so sure about the `bash` example. Isn't the first line read, then the correct program spawned to execute it? That is, if you change the first line to `#!/bin/sh`, then it's not the same language anymore. Your final example is right on the mark, though!

Comment: IDK, that one does get a bit ambiguous, since it's handled by the OS. I tend to think of it as a comment since it would be in Ruby, which is what I mostly work with, but you could format it such that you pass flags to the binary, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env ruby -s` which would keep the same language, but change how it treats ARGV.

Comment: The point of shebang is that when you execute the program as "./myprog", the OS reads the first line and launches the specified interpreter. Then the interpreter ignores that line as a comment (or if the interpreter is Perl, reads it for flags). `#!/user/bin/bash` is still ignored as a comment if you "run" the program as "sh myprog". So the line is a comment to the shell interpreting the script, but meaningful to the OS if the script is executed as a program -- your call whether or not a different meaning to different readers is "magic".

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about that remark in Wikipedia. I think the intention is just to say that a comment "should not" affect behavior (since that's what comment means), so if it does then it must be some kind of special case and hence is "magic" by the definition in use in that section of the article. The author of that line of the article didn't necessarily have any particular language in mind.

If you fancy being pedantic, then a comment can easily affect program behavior in C (in this example by containing a number of line breaks):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    /* If this multi-line comment were deleted, then
       the line-numbers in the remainder of the file
       would be smaller. Boring magic.
    */
    printf("%d\n", __LINE__);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this is *not* what the author of the remark intended, so the remark isn't precise. It's special cases of the comment syntax that are "magic".

Comment: Good example, I hadn't thought about `__LINE__`!

Answer (score 0):

You do also get those "magic" comments...
That commented out section where everything works fine if you leave those comments in. You remove them and then *poof*, nothing works. (These are usually caused by having one line in the middle of the commented section uncommented)

(Commentting is Magic)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? If there is one line in the comment that is uncommented, deleting that is not "comment" magic anymore!

Comment: Sorry, forgot I'd commented here.
And pressed enter for line feed, and submitted(!)

The line that looks like comment magic is often an "x = True" in the middle of 200 lines of scar tissue, and in those 200 lines, the only line which is not commented, so you undelete the whole comment block and go "I dunno how that fixed it, but this commented out scar tissue code is essential!"